# Configurable product page is showing price twice in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, ecommerce-tracking

I am using flaton magento template. I have replaced the catalog.xml  code

From

```
<reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
 <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
 </reference>
```

To

```
<reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable"[![enter image description here][1]][1]
            as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.renderers" as="attr_renderers" />
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.after" as="after" />
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Now this showing price twice

Answer (score 0):

I think you have given price for the configurable product as well as simple product. So the Price of the configurable product will be added to the Simple product. If you want to keep the price of the simple product only you can just give the price of configurable product as zero.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The price is showed twice ("$1 $1"), not doubled ($2)